# Asp.Net Core & JWT authentication: How to know authentication failed because token expired?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, jwt

Below is the JWT authentication I am using:

```
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    // options.SaveToken = false;
    // options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(AuthConfig.GetSecretKey(Configuration)),

        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,

        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
    };

    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnChallenge = c =>
        {
            c.HandleResponse();

            // TODO: How to know if the token was expired?

            return AspNetUtils.WriteJsonAsync(c.Response, new Result<string> 
            { 
                Message = "Unauthenticated.", 
                IsError = true 
            }, 401);
        },
    };
});
```

The authentication is working fine. For new requirements, I need to know if authentication failed because the JWT token was expired or not.

**Note that authentication failed because of multi reasons**. The token can be missing, tampered, or expired.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {
            if(context.Exception is SecurityTokenExpiredException)
            {
                // if you end up here, you know that the token is expired
            }
        }
    };
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [OnChallenge](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbearerevents.onchallenge?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DDE-DE%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerEvents.OnChallenge);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=aspnetcore-2.2) property:

```
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnChallenge = context =>
        {
            if (context?.AuthenticateFailure is SecurityTokenExpiredException)
            {
                var error = context.Error; // "invalid_token"
                var errorDescription = context.ErrorDescription; // "The token is expired"
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```